# Installation of dtaidistance in python provides error

Tags: python, installation, pip, dtw

I am trying to install the module dtaidistance in Python to calculate the DTW distance matrix for a set of time series. But whenever I try to install the package using "pip install dtaidistance" a large error pops up and I don't know how to interpret it and what to do in order to make it function.

See the final few lines and the corresponding error message after running the install in the anaconda prompt in the screenshot below:

Error code screenshot:

[image: Error code screenshot]

Comment: Check what version of Python is needed for the latest version of the library. Perhaps you need to update your Python version (or pip).

Answer (score 0):

The error says the `cl.exe` binary is not found. This probably means that you have not installed the Microsoft C compiler and linker (MSVC or Microsoft Visual Studio for Windows).

By the way, the current version of DTAIDistance should continue installing the Python implementation but the fast C-based versions will not be available.